# Jackson Ignor From Another Java Class

Tags: java, json, spring

I want the Employee object to only display the id property when adding a CV. When I put @JsonIgnore on the employee object in the CV, the id doesn't come either. How can I hide property that I do not want to appear in employee class (password, national identity) on the CV class?
Cv Class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cvs")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CV {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id")
    private Employee employee;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cv", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    List<Education> educations;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cv", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    List<Work> works;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cv", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    List<Languege> langueges;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cv", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    List<Technology> technologies;

    @Column(name = "github")
    private String github;

    @Column(name = "linkedin")
    private String linkedin;

    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "cover_letter")
    private String coverLetter;

    @Column(name = "photo")
    private String photo;

}
```

Employee Class :

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "employees")
@Entity

@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
public class Employee extends User {

    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "first_name", length = 50)
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "last_name", length = 50)
    private String lastName;

    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "national_identity", length = 11)
    private String nationalIdentity;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "year_of_birth")
    private int yearOfBirth;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "employee")
    private CV cv;
}
```

I read data this format;

```
{
  "id": 0,
  "employee": {
    "id": 0, //visible
    "email": "string", //not visible
    "password": "string", //not visible
    "firstName": "string", 
    "lastName": "string",
    "nationalIdentity": "string", //not visible
    "yearOfBirth": 0 //not visible
  },
  "educations": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "schoolName": "string",
      "department": "string",
      "startingDate": "2022-02-11",
      "graduationDate": "2022-02-11"
    }
  ],
  "works": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "workplace": "string",
      "job": {
        "id": 0,
        "jobName": "string"
      },
      "startingDate": "2022-02-11",
      "endDate": "2022-02-11"
    }
  ],
  "langueges": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "languege": "string",
      "level": 0
    }
  ],
  "technologies": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "technology": "string"
    }
  ],
  "github": "string",
  "linkedin": "string",
  "coverLetter": "string",
  "photo": "string"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom serializer that you would use on your CV employee field : `@JsonSerialize(using = CustomEmployeeSerializer.class)`

```
public class CustomEmployeeSerializer extends SerializerBase<Employee> {

public CustomEmployeeSerializer() {
    super(Employee.class, true);
}

@Override
public void serialize(Employee employee, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider)
    throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    jgen.writeString(employee.getId());
}
```